# Hierarchical Bayes - How to code 'None of the above' option

Tags: r, bayesian

I am programming in R using hierarchical bayes for a choice-based conjoint task and wondering how to code the "none of the above" option in the design matrix?

The R code that I am using is below, which contains the rhierMnlRwMixture() function from the bayesm package. The response options are from two product bundles plus a none of the above option (i.e. 3 response options in total).

Is it correct to use all 0's in the third row of the design matrix which relates to the none of the above option (example for respondent 1 first choice)?

R code:

```
mcmc=list(R=20000,keep=10)  
library(bayesm)
out=rhierMnlRwMixture(Data=list(p=3,lgtdata=lgtdata),Prior=list(ncomp=1),Mcmc=mcmc)
```

If I were to look at respondent 1 data it would like this, answering choice 3 and x is the design matrix.

```
lgtdata[[1]]

$y

[1] 3

$X    
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]

 [1,]    1    0    0    0    1    
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Take a look at `ChoiceModelR` package. Imho, it is better suited for real life conjoint analysis than `bayesm`.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at this